# ID3Info problem with Perl script

Tags: perl

I'm trying to get an MP3 file's information from ID3 tags.

```
my $output_file = `ls | egrep '\.flac$|\.mp3$'`;
$output_file = "$output_folder\/$output_file"; 
my $artist = "id3info \"$output_file\" | grep '^=== TPE1' | sed -e 's/.*: //g'"
my $album = "id3info \"$output_file\" | grep '^=== TALB' | sed -e 's/.*: //g'";
my $format = "MP3";
my $bitrate = "id3info \"$output_file\" | grep 'Bitrate' | sed -e 's/.*: //g'";
my $genretags = "id3info \"$output_file\" | grep '=== TCON' | sed -e 's/.*: //g', mix, auto.up";
$genretags =~ tr/[A-Z]/[a-z]/;
```

However this returns the following error: 
`syntax error at mp3.pl line 88, near "my "
Global symbol "$album" requires explicit package name at mp3.pl line 88.
Global symbol "$album" requires explicit package name at mp3.pl line 173.`

Could someone advise on what this error means? What package do I need to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me introduce you to [MP3::Tag](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MP3-Tag/)

```
use MP3::Tag;

my $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($filename);

# get some information about the file in the easiest way
my($title, $track, $artist, $album, $comment, $year, $genre) = $mp3->autoinfo();
```

*This code above was copied (nearly) verbatim from the examples shown in `MP3::Tag`'s documentation.*

Answer (score 3):

```
my $artist = "id3info \"$output_file\" | grep '^=== TPE1' | sed -e 's/.*: //g'"
```

You forgot to terminate the above line with a `;`.

Yes, of course, you should be using a module to parse the tags.

Comment: ohh, thanks. I'm also trying out MP3::Tag now. Seems a bit more cleaner :)

Comment: _[Dean](http://stackoverflow.com/users/422687/dean)_: You are welcome. A specialised module is the way to go. :-)